# Data storage in innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am new to mysql administration and I came to know about the data storage in myisam is through `.frm`, `.myd` and `.myi`. I could not find the data storage mechanism in InnoDB rather than its storage in tablespace.

Could anyone help me to sort out the storage mechanism in innodb storage machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Table format files (.frm files) that contain a description of table structure. Every
  table has its own .frm file, located in the appropriate database directory. This is
  true no matter which storage engine manages the table.
- The InnoDB storage engine has its own tablespace and log files. The tablespace
  contains data and index information for all InnoDB tables, as well as the undo
  logs that are needed if a transaction must be rolled back. The log files record
  information about committed transactions and are used to ensure that no data loss
  occurs. By default, the tablespace and log files are located in the data directory.
  The default tablespace file is named ibdata1 and the default log files are named
  ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1. (It is also possible to configure InnoDB to use
  one tablespace file per table. In this case, InnoDB creates the tablespace file for a
  given table in the table's database directory.)
- Each InnoDB table is represented on disk by an .frm format file in the database
  directory, as well as data and index storage in the InnoDB tablespace. The InnoDB
  tablespace is a logical single storage area that is made up of one or more files or
  partitions on disk. By default, InnoDB uses a single tablespace that is shared by
  all InnoDB tables. The tablespace is stored in machine-independent format. It is
  implemented such that table sizes can exceed the maximum file size allowed by
  the filesystem. It is also possible to configure InnoDB to create each table with its
  own tablespace.
- MySQL represents each MyISAM table using three files: a format file that
  stores the definition of the table structure, a data file that stores the contents of
  table rows, and an index file that stores any indexes on the table. These files are
  distinguished from one another by their suffixes. For example, the format, data,
  and index files for a table named mytable are called mytable.frm, mytable.MYD,
  and mytable.MYI.